# How to write this format in string builder in c#

Tags: c#, xml

my xml file property like this:

```
 <Attributes>
        public function attr($attr, $value) {
            $this->attributes[$attr] = $value;
            return $this;
        }
      </Attributes>
```

i get from c#[image]

How to write this function from image

```
function ajaxSettings($value){
  return $this -> ajaxSettings = $value;
}
```

Comment: Do you want this to put in a stringbuilder variable ? Elaborate your question.

Comment: yes i writing string builder varaible

Comment: string.AppendFormat() - this is case i dont know how to pass arguments

Comment: what string you want in your stringbuilder variable? the whole xml or what ? elaborate your question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `StringBuilder`'s [`AppendFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b(v=vs.110).aspx), you use the standard [string formatting notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting) to insert one or more values in your string:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

var world = "World";

sb.AppendFormat("Hello {0}", world);

var helloWorld = sb.ToString(); // returns "Hello World"
```